# Reusing Domain Name for New Content and Permanently removing beta site indexed content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, seo

I have three problems with my site deployed on IIS 7+.

1. I am reusing my existing domain name for a completely different content than the old one. Problem is the old site is indexed by google but the content is no longer available on the new site. How do I remove the old content index on google?
2. I hosted a beta site on AWS and added tons of test data to it. I didn't knew about  Robots.txt so the site was crawled. This site was only accessible via an IP. I have now moved my production site on the same server and linked the ip to top level domains. Issue is the old test data comes up in search and redirected to the production site via the ip link. Test data is no longer available
3. I have two top level domains .co.in and .in both pointing to the same server. Do I need to configure something so that I do not get the google penalty of duplicate content?

I have searched the forum and web but not sure how to configure 301 or 302 for my mvc 3 app

Pinakin

Answer (score 0):

1. You can submit a request to google for them to remove content from their index (http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663416) but it might not happen for a while.  Google will automatically drop the content from it's index if it no longer exists.  In the meantime you should use URL Rewriting to return a response from your server as follows

   - Issue a `301 Moved Permanently` if the content is still available at a different location
   - Issue a `303 See Other` if a contextually similar content to the missing content is still available at a different location
   - Issue a `404 Not Found` if the content is simply no longer available
2. For the test data url's set up URL rewriting to issue a `404 Not Found`.  This will force search engine to drop the missing content from it;s indexes.  It won;t happen immediately, but it will happen eventually.
3. Set up an IIS Rewrite rule so that `.co.in` redirects to `.in` (or vice versa).  This will ensure that although your content can be accessed from multiple domains, you only have 1 primary domain and so search engines will not penalise you from duplicate content